# Вывод значений всех переменных в конец?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
int main(void) 
{ 

char *p, c; 

int *a, b; 

float *x, y = 3.5; 

double *m, n; 

printf("p: char: start address %p \n", &p); 

printf("c: char: start address %p \n", &c);

printf("a: int: start address %p \n", &a); 

printf("b: int: start address %p \n", &b); 

printf("x: float: start address %p \n", &x); 

printf("y: float: start address %p \n", &y); 

printf("m: double: start address %p \n", &m); 

printf("n: double: start address %p \n", &n); 

a = &b; 
printf(" Enter b = "); 

scanf("%d", a); 

printf("a=%p\t*a=%d\tb=%d\n", a, *a, b); 

p =(char*) a; 

c=*p; 

p=p+3; 

p=&c; 

printf("p=%p\tc=%d\ta=%p\tb=%d\n", p, c, a, b); 

x = &y; 

printf("x=%p\t*x=%f\ty=%f\n", x, *x, y); 

a = (int*)x; 

*a = *x; 

printf("a=%p\t*a=%d\tx=%p\t*x=%f\ty=%f\n", a, *a, x, *x, y); 

a = &b; 

y = 12345.6789; 

printf("x=%p\t*x=%f\ty=%f\n", x, *x, y); 

p = (char*)x; 

c=*p; 

*p=*p+3; 

*p=c; 

printf("p=%p\tc=%d\tx=%p\ty=%f\n", p, c, x, y); 

m = &n; 

n=0; 

printf("m=%p\t*m=%lf\tn=%lf\n", m, *m, n); 

n = 5.5; 

printf("m=%p\t*m=%lf\tn=%lf\n", m, *m, n); 

b = n = y = 1.7; 

printf("b=%d\ty=%f\tn=%lf\n", b, y, n); 

printf("*a=%d\t*x=%f\t*m=%lf\n", *a, *x, *m); 

m += 2; 

printf("n=%lf\tn=%p\tm=%p\n", n, &n, m); 

*m = (float)*a - n + (int)*x; 

printf("m=%p\t*m=%lf\n", m, *m); 

system("pause"); 

return 0; 

}
```

вывод  в конец – значений всех переменных. Как это записать?

Comment: "вывод в конец" - что это значит? О чем речь вообще?

Comment: в начало программы добавить вывод на экран адресов всех пере-менных, а в конец – значений всех переменных( при запуске программы в конце должно выводить значение всех переменных

Comment: И что вам мешает это сделать? У вас же стоят там `printf`, чем они вас не устраивают?

Comment: Вы можете написать оригинальный текст задания? А то как то скомкано описали. Что дано, что нужно сделать, с помощью чего это писать нужно, и соответствующе на какой "экран" Вас просят вывести все, например в отдельном окне или в консоли или в эмуляторе чего-то. И главное - что это за код который Вы привели - это исходный код или это уже Вы пытались что-то сделать. Если пытались что-то сделать - то напишите что именно не получается.

Comment: Можете более подробно объяснить суть вопроса?